# Given a transfer function i want an op amp represantation

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I have a project for my university on the transfer function (where a,b,c are constants):

$$G(s)=\frac{(s+a)}{(s^2+bs+c)}$$

and I'm asking how to represent this whole thing with an OPAmp circuit.

(The difficult part that got me the most time thinking, is the numerator)
I would like some help in order to implement it myself and not an immediate  solution.

Comment: Your transfer function has one zero and two poles. There's many ways to implement this using op-amps. One thing to consider is that the best implementation might depend on whether the poles are real or complex.

Comment: Look at 'controller canonic' form of a TF. This method has no restriction on real/complex poles.

Comment: Are you expected to vary a, b and c independently and demonstrate what happens or are you looking for any op-amp solution that is if the general form of your equation. Think about this because one option is really tricky.

Comment: i have specific values for a,b,c ... poles are complex.
I just wanted some general help so i didn't fit in the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this is 2nd-order, consider the [Sallen-Key circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology) and add to it [another op-amp circuit that sums (with weighting factors)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier) the voltages at \$V_\text{OUT}\$ and \$V_\text{x}\$.  (reference to Figure 1.)